# Exception while accessing a shared EXE by multiple threads

Tags: multithreading

I have a requirement where I need to spawn multiple threads to execute a process. here the process is an exe. I'm facing a problem while multiple threads try to access the exe which is in a shared path.
I tried using a lock .even that din't help. Any help appreciated.Please find the code below.

```
Task t;
            t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                //lock (thisLock)
                //{
                //    process = ProcessHelper.StartNew(objPSI.FileName, objPSI.Arguments, true, 5000);
                //    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                //    process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
                //}
                process = ProcessHelper.StartNew(objPSI);
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
                //}
                //var token = Task.Factory.CancellationToken;
                //Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                //{
                //    //this.label1.Text = "Task past first work section...";
                //}, token, TaskCreationOptions.None, context);

            }
            )
            .ContinueWith(_ =>
                {

                    if (process.ExitCode != 0)
                    {
                        ErrorTexts.Add(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ProgressText = "::: Migration Successful";
                    }
                    process.Close();
                });
```

Comment: what is the EXACT exception? What are you really trying to achieve here?

Comment: Actually I'm developing a wizard to migrate Access mdb files to SQL server.To achieve this I'm using SSMA.exe file which is available for free.

Comment: SSMA allows to migrate only one .mdb file at a time so 
I have introduced a feature to select multiple files and spawn multiple threads to call the same exe many times.say I have chosen 4 mdb files.then 4 threads will run parallel y and each thread execution progress has to be shown on the UI Label or something like that.

Comment: the code that I have posted works perfectly fine when I just migrate one .mdb file. when I choose multiple.all the threads try to access the  ssma.exe which is in a shared path.eventually it breaks saying unable to access ssma.exe as it is being used by another process.

Comment: I tried adding a lock for the process creation part.but that din't help.

Comment: well, I wouldn't understand why SSMA would be locked since you are not writing to that file (but only executing). perhaps SSMA does not allow for it to be run multiple times and only 1 instance is allowed. have you checked to see if this is the case? I do not see any code where a NEW PROCESS object is created in your multiple threads being spawned.

Comment: SSMA allows.I checked that. earlier I used Backgroundworker to test this.but with backgroundworker the UI was unresponsive. So make the UI I used Task Factory class , it solved the UI problem but now I have run into this issue. with Baclgroundworker I was able to add a lock but with Task factory lock doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: the BGW cannot be "unresponsive". your code must have been incorrect in such a case. using the Task Factory for what you are doing is not quite the way to go. Post your ENTIRE code and not just the short snippet there as there are variables that we do not know about or how you are even instantiating it.

Comment: Ahmed.How do I share the code. Its too big to be accommodated in comments.suggest a way as I'm new to SO.